# Find command result, won't write to the output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have below script, Need find all PDF associate pages in website .
PDF_Search_File.txt content the URL of the PDF file

```
Example : /static/pdf/pdf1.pdf
          /static/pdf/pdf2.pdf
```

But find result not writing to the output file.there  is and issue below line

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l '$name' '{}' \; >>output_pdf_new.txt
```

Any information will help.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="PDF_Search_File.txt"
while read -r line
do
        name="$line"
                echo "*******pdf******** - $name\n" >>output_pdf_new.txt
        find . -type f -exec grep -l '$name' '{}' \; >>output_pdf_new.txt
                echo "*******pdf******** - $name\n" >>output_pdf_new.txt
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: No this not working ether , I have tested

Answer (score 1):

The variable $name should be in double quotes `"$name"` instead of single quotes. This is typical shell behaviour dealing with single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that since your redirecting the output to a file echo is not displaying the text, you can use `tee -a` to do both, for instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="PDF_Search_File.txt"
while read -r line
do
        name="$line"
        echo "*******pdf******** - $name" | tee -a output_pdf_new.txt
        find . -type f -exec grep -l "$name" '{}' \; | tee -a output_pdf_new.txt
        echo "*******pdf******** - ${name}" | tee -a output_pdf_new.txt
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: I can see the echo output in output text file , problem is find result not writing to output file look like below .
   /Search_pdf.sh
    *******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf1.pdf\n
   *******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf1.pdf\n
./Search_pdf.sh
*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf2.pdf\n
*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf2.pdf\n
./Search_pdf.sh
*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf3.pdf\n
*******pdf******** - /static/pdf/pdf3.pdf\n

Comment: also added the variables inside the double quotes as suggested on other comments